# How custom the design of UIButton in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uibutton, tweak

I need help to create a custom UIButton, I'm creating a tweak, i have an custom uiview and i know how to add a button on it.

But i don't like the blue and tiny stock style of it, I want to custom my button like my UIView with color style and size but don't know how to.

I want something like this : [Image of button style I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROYEH.png)

Comment: UIButton, style set to custom and change it's color properties. For rounded corners set layer's corner radius property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom Button style can be achieved like below.

**Objective-C**

CustomButton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIImage (Utils)

+ (UIImage *)imageWithSize:(CGSize)size color:(UIColor *)color;

@end

@interface CustomButton : UIButton

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;

@end
```

CustomButton.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation UIImage (Utils)

+ (UIImage *)imageWithSize:(CGSize)size color:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0);
    [color setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height));
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

@end

@implementation CustomButton: UIButton

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

        UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageWithSize:self.bounds.size color:UIColor.blackColor];
        [self setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitleColor:UIColor.whiteColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 40.0;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0 weight:UIFontWeightRegular];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Swift**

CustomButton.swift

```
struct AppStyles {

    struct ActionButton {
        static let backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        static let textColor = UIColor.white
        static let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .regular)
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithSize(_ size: CGSize, color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let style: AppStyles.ActionButton.Type = AppStyles.ActionButton.self
        let backgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithSize(self.bounds.size, color: style.backgroundColor)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: UIControl.State())
        self.setTitleColor(style.textColor, for: UIControl.State())
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 40.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true


        if let label = self.titleLabel {
            label.font = style.font
        }

        self.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Drag and drop UIButton to your UIView in your storyboard and make class in `Identity Inspector` as `CustomButton` and add constraints as required. Thats it.

Please find the resultant screenshot. Hope it helps.

[image]